# Creating an array from two data-* and one select array codeigniter

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a table with products where i can add rows dynamically and on each row i add it will be a `select` and an edit `button`.

If i press this `button`,it will display a modal where i can modify 2 data-* of the select.The dependence(dep) and the category.

After editing one `select`, i will have something like this:

```
<select data-dep="1" data-category="3"></select>
```

After submitting,in the model,i will get the products like this:

```
$products = $this->input->post('products[]');
```

In this way, i will have an array with all the products i wanted to add to database.The question is, can i make an array with the id of the product(what i have now), the value from data-dep and the value from data-category?And if i can,how?Something like this:

```
[1]--->product_id = 1,dep = 3, category = 2;

[2]--->product_id = 2,dep = 1, category = 3;
```

My HTML is this:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="container-div">
            <table id="dynamic">
                <tr id="row1">
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control select-table" name="products[]" id="select-1" data-dep="" data-category="">
                            <?php foreach($products as $product):?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $product['products_id'];?>"><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        </select>
                        <i id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" class="fas fa-edit fa-lg edit-div"></i>
                        <div id="plus-div"><span><i class="fas fa-plus fa-lg"></i></span></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <label>Pret:</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Creaza meniul" style="margin-top: 5px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <select class="form-control dep-select" id="dep-test" name="dep-select">
                        <option class="form-group" value="1">Fara garnitura&salata</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="2">Fara salata</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="3">Fara garnitura</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="4">Cu de toate</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control category-select" name="category-select">
                        <option class="form-group" value="1">Fel Principal</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="2">Garnitura</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="3">Salata</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="4">Supa</option>
                        <option class="form-group" value="5">Desert</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" data-dismiss="modal">Salveaza</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Inchide</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you "submitting" this data to PHP?

Comment: I have a form_open to a controller and in that controller i call a function from model where i get the products[] values and i add them to database.

Comment: But how do you get the data from the model including the `data-*` attributes to php. How is the form data submitted?

Comment: That's the ideea.
I don't know how to get the data-* and how to make the array

Comment: `data-*` are for JS not php and do not get submitted with a form. You would have to write an `ajax` call with JS or jQuery grabbing that data and then sending it over.